# C# - Font (from Resources) "name" does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, fonts, access-violation, font-family

So, just so nobody is confused, the setup is basically the main solution and then a second solution with the custom controls in it. The first picture is from the main solution and it shows the error I'm getting on runtime. I use `GetFontFromBytes` to use the font files I have tucked away in the project Resources. The second picture is from the second solution.What I'm trying to do is have one of my controls spawn a number of other controls as children
[image]
[image]
Below is the code I wrote to get access to my fonts.

```
private Font GetFontFromBytes(byte[] bytes, float size)
{
    PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(bytes.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, bytes.Length);
    pfc.AddMemoryFont(ptr, bytes.Length);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);
    return new Font(pfc.Families[0], size);
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated. If more information is required just let me know what you need.

**EDIT**
I've moved from loading the font in via memory to a local file for the sake of testing and convenience. However, out of the blue I'm now getting an issue loading the first font in and no fonts after that will load because the first font not loading in (error: CS0103 "The name 'name' does not exist in the current context"). If there is any other way to use custom fonts besides `PrivateFontCollection` please let me know, otherwise I need some sort of fix to my issue.

**EDIT2**
Also should be noted that my code has been adjusted to only free allocated memory and dispose of the (god-awful) PFC when the form closes.

Comment: There's something strange about the PrivateFontCollection class, *everybody* get this wrong over and over again.  Probably a google link to a crappy web page, SO answers don't seem to be able to replace it.  You cannot call Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() until the font can never be used again.  Doing it anyway produces a dangling pointer bug, the kind of bug that does not cause failure nearly often enough.  You got lucky, most programmers nurse a "text looks corrupted" problem.

Comment: Changed the code to create the `Font` before the memory is freed and then afterward returns the Font instance. My result, however, did not change. Still getting the same error.

Comment: The rule is a simple one and matches all .NET rules about resource management.  ,You must call the PrivateFontCollection.Dispose() method when you *know* that you are no longer going to use any private fonts anymore.  Only then can you call FreeCoTaskMem().  Discovering that the only time you can safely call the Dispose() method is when your app terminates an inconvenient truth and entirely normal.  So don't bother.

Comment: Yeah but after this method is called I never use PrivateFontCollection again. I only use it momentarily to convert the font files in the project resources to usable `Font` instances.

Comment: It is supposed to be obvious that when you use a Font that is provided by PrivateFontCollection then you actually continue to use PrivateFontCollection.  Dispose the PFC, like you should, and all fonts provided by it go up in smoke as well.  Find the right place to call Dispose() and then you found the right place to call FreeCoTaskMem().

Comment: This is actually getting extremely aggravating (not your fault). Now I'm getting this issue when loading the second font. I've changed my code to do what you said. I've also moved from using the embedded resources to files on the drive and nothing. Is there no other way of embedding fonts? If not, I need some other solution.

Comment: Have you happened to find a solution? I'm facing a similar issue every time I do a System.Drawing.Font() it seems to find the font but throws an error when I try to make use of it.